# Laravel 4 - File Upload

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Form where among other info, a user would upload an image. I want to store the path to the image on the database and save the image to the `public/img/` folder on the Server.

The form was opened using: `{{ Form::open(['route'=>'pizzas.store', 'files'=>true]) }}`so that it would be able to POST files. Inspecting the HTML I have the folowing:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://mypizza/pizzas" 
  accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I can POST to my Controller and receive all the data from the Form as expected. The method handling the file is as follows:

```
public function store() {
    //TODO -  Validation

    $destinationPath = '';
    $filename        = '';

    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
        $file            = Input::file('image');
        $destinationPath = '/img/';
        $filename        = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    }


    $pizza = Pizza::create(['name'       => Input::get('name'),
                           'price'       => Input::get('price'),
                           'ingredients' => Input::get('ingredients'),
                           'active'      => Input::get('active'),
                           'path'        => $destinationPath . $filename]);

    if ($pizza) {
        return Redirect::route('pizzas.show', $pizza->id);
    }

    //TODO - else
}
```

When I select a File and Submit the Form, everything seems to work, except that no file is saved on the `/img` folder. The database registers the file path and name correctly.

Running `dd($uploadSuccess);`right after the `if { ...}`block, I get the following:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File)#220 (2) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(17) "/img\YZmLw7_2.jpg"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(12) "YZmLw7_2.jpg" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In addition to the answer from [Reflic], it will be necessary to adjust the `path` on the database as follows: `'path' => 'img/' . $filename]);`

Comment: Thats right, i have forgotten this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your **$destination_path** is wrong. You have to include the path to the /public directory in your variable $destination like this:

`$destinationPath = public_path().'/img/';`

Answer (score 3):

Since you appear to be using php 5.4 you also might consider using [Stapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler).  It's quite stable now (will be out of beta very shortly) and would save you from a lot of the boilerplate that you're having to write right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$destinationPath= public_path() . 'img/';
```

answer given by @Reflic may br right... but not for me.... 
this path worked for me.
it may because i removed "public/" from url...
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. I got everything right about my code except for the

```
public_path()
```

Wasn't prepending to the my folder

```
$destinationPath= public_path() . '/img/'; // Worked perfect
```

I also did this to change my file name

I got the file extension

```
$extension = Input::file('YourFileName')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename = WhateverYouWantHere . '.' . $extension;
```

And that is it, file name changed. Laravel is indeed wonderful

Answer (score 1):

you can write relative path also.
like as

`$destinationPath="resources/assets/images/";`

or

`$destinationPath= 'public/img/';`